How did Kapitänleutnant Franz Buchner lure the destroyer into a mine?
How did Kapitänleutnant Franz Buchner lure the destroyer into a mine?
Please explain Kapitänleutnant Buchner's ruse in this video. It is from Season 4 (2023) of the TV series Das Boot. I forgot which episode. If you know, just edit my post and add it.




The cable attached to the mine, when they were laying them, became ensnared, so they were dragging it behind them, making extra noise and because of its buoyancy, it was dragging on the surface, where the destroyer could see 'something' generating a wake. Chasing the wake, probably believing it to be a periscope of an enemy submarine, the destroyer chases it down. At a certain point, in the torpedo room they are able to cut the cable, dive deeper and change course, the mine, now free, is left in the path of the destroyer (which would be unable to change course in time) and detonates on impact.

I'm not sure if that was the question you were asking, but that is what clearly happens in the scene (before they use two more fish). Not sure if you are aware but submarines were not just built as 'submarines', some were dedicated mine-layers, some did both (as seen here), some were just for cargo, some were for dedicated anti-aircraft operations, etc.

@blobbymcblobby thanks. yep! you are right "that was the question you were asking". kindly post your comments as an answer?


How did Kapitänleutnant Franz Buchner lure the destroyer into a mine?

From the scene I can see that:
The cable attached to the mine, when they were laying them,

became ensnared, so they were
dragging it behind them,
making extra noise and
because of its buoyancy, it was dragging on the surface, where
the destroyer could see 'something' generating a wake.
Chasing the wake, probably believing it to be a periscope of an enemy submarine, the destroyer chases it down. At a certain point, in the torpedo room they are able to
cut the cable,
dive deeper and
change course,
the mine, now free, is left in the path of the destroyer (which would be unable to change course in time) and
detonates on impact. –

(for the idea that the cable was ensnared, most mines, when deployed from the tube, a safety latch springs out on the mine, pulling a bowden wire. The wire playing out unlocks the spindle of a hydrostatic clock, and at a set depth the mine is armed - this prevents unhappy accidents within the submarine or detonations too close to the submarine (which had happened before))
Note: for the mine portrayed it was one of the TMA type series, and IIRC the TMA early version is the only one that moored as portrayed in the episode. The error could be that the mooring line deployed early and was playing out before it hit the seabed and whilst too close to the submarine that launched it (from the bow, to the stern)
This shows correct sequence, laying mines at start of the scene:

Mine is launched from tube, drops to sea bed, wire plays out allowing mine to float up, mine is ready.
This shows a recently launched mine deployment going wrong:

This shows the buoyant mine on the surface, creating a wake that the enemy ship can see and chase:

Using the wake as bait, they cut the mine at the right time to allow it to float up into the path of the enemy ship:


Both World Wars produced developments in submarines that were not just built as 'submarines' - some were dedicated mine-layers, some did both (as seen here), some were just for cargo, some were for dedicated anti-aircraft operations, etc.
Types of German naval mines:

Mine layers:
Russia actually started building the worlds first submarine mine layer Krab in 1912, but it was still under construction when the Germans beat them to it in launching their Type UCImine laying submarines in 1915.

Early concepts:
Dropping mines out the back of a tube (with internal racks), once on the sea bed or predetermined depth the mine separates from base spindle, and floats up.


Krab dropped them out of a ramped tube, like laying eggs (which is the same translation in the episode: laying eggs).
Modern concept by WW2:

Usual types of mines were either ground mines that rested in shallow water, dormant mines that can moored deep, but can rise on occasion - you could have mines on clock timers, so they only activated at a certain time, (then went dormant again until Tuesday afternoon, for example), buoyant mines - some of which might have been at constant depth or some that rise and fall with the tide, and some mines are just set to drift..
Some mines also had a set period of time in which they were active, after which they scuttled themselves. Most mines had a sort of anti-tamper mechanism of some type to defeat disarming or sweeping.
https://www.history.navy.mil/browse-by-topic/exploration-and-innovation/naval-mine-warfare.html
Others:
Flak u-boat - shortlived idea of trapping aircraft so they could be shot down by modified anti-aircraft flak-gun u-boats in the Bay of Biscay:

Cargo submarine:

